# Is it OK to use 12-3 awg to wire a ceiling fan and light?

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan

In a 2000 era home in Georgia, I replaced an overhead lighting fixture with a combo ceiling fan and light.  (Yes, I reinforced the junction box appropriately.)

The wiring was simple enough, the power supply is via the switch box (now two switches).  The question is:  **For the wiring that runs between the switch box and the fan & light, can I use a single 3-conductor cable instead of two 2-conductor cables?**  Electrically, it works.  Safety and code issues?

Ground and neutral connect through the switch box to both fan and light.  I split the incoming hot (black) to supply both switches, then on the outbound side I ran one switched hot for the fan (via the red), and the switched hot for the light (via the black).

It's not just that I'm cheap (I am). The rationale for doing this is that it was easier to pull a replacement single 3-conductor wire rather than pull a second 2-conductor cable.

Comment: Lights are usually wired with 14awg. Are you sure yours isn't? I wouldn't upsize wire. It can give the impression of a larger current capacity downstream.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about that, the guy replacing the breaker should be going by the wire size at the breaker, which should be correct or labeled.

Comment: Heh, if you ever need a job as an electrician ;)

Comment: @isherwood - Yes, it's overkill to use 12 gauge for lighting, but it's on a 20 A circuit - so that's what is needed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no problem at all with what you've done. In fact, that's the way it's supposed to be done.  If you were to use two /2 cables, you'd either be paralleling the neutral (310.4), and/or not running all the circuit conductors together (300.3(B)). Parallel neutrals are not allowed in this situation, so you've actually avoided a code violation by doing it with /3 cable. You've also kept all the circuit conductors in a single cable, and avoided violating that code section.

Comment: Yep, nearly all light/fan combos are wired this way during construction. I wasn't aware that parallel neutrals were a violation. What's the potential danger?

Comment: Electromagnetic heating is the main problem to avoid by running wires together. From the 2014 NEC "300.3(B) Conductors of the Same Circuit. All conductors of the same circuit and, where used, the grounded conductor and all equipment grounding conductors and bonding con- ductors shall be contained within the same raceway, auxiliary gutter, cable tray, cablebus assembly, trench, cable, or cord, unless otherwise permitted in accordance with 300.3(B)(1) through (B)(4)."

Comment: 310.4 Conductors in Parallel:                                
Aluminum, copper-clad aluminum, or copper conductors of size 1/0 AWG and larger, comprising each phase, polarity, neutral, or grounded circuit conductor shall be permitted to be connected in parallel (electrically joined at both ends).

Comment: @BenWelborn are you just quoting the code section, or suggesting that the OP might use 1/0 or larger conductors to feed the fan/light?

Comment: @Tester101 310.4 makes few exceptions; in a nutshell, wire smaller than 1/0 cannot be run parallel.

Comment: @BenWelborn I know, that's what I said in the post.  Is there a problem with the post, or are you just adding more information?

Comment: Yeah, I recently hooked up some 1000kcmil in parallel.  Interesting thing is - each wire had its own fuse.

Comment: @tester101 310.4 is a supporting reference that specifically adresses parallel conductors. isherwood questioned the violation and danger of parallel neutrals. ArchonOSX provided a response to isherwood's question about danger, and an NEC reference to support your statement that, "not running all the circuit conductors together [would be a violation]", but 300.3 does not address the issue of parallel wiring which is a violation in this case (whether it is in the same cable or not) which was basically unanswered- or at least left room for clarification.

Comment: @BenWelborn oh, okay.  Thank you.  I guess I should have quoted the relevant code sections in the answer.

Comment: Normally, I would not think so, but hindsight is 20/20. I personally appreciate a concise answer, but it's hard to predetermine what constitutes an appropriate amount of information. I have found myself discussing the nature of electrons at work before... all because I wanted to be concise. Now we have spent too much time on this.

Comment: is it possible to be code compliant with 2 conduits if the second neutral remained unconnected?

Comment: @ratchetfreak No, then you're still violating 300.3(B).

Comment: @Tester101 or more accurately, the second white remained unconnected on both ends (in the switch and in the fan's box). So it's not a second neutral but an unconnected floating wire.